# FileSystemWatcher not firing events on linux within a console app with a hosted service

Tags: linux, .net-core, filesystemwatcher

Hello I am currently attempting to implement the FileSystemWatcher within a console application that runs a hosted service and I cannot seem to get my implementation to fire the events when changes to the file system occur.

Here is an example of my code in the program.cs of my console application.

```
await new HostBuilder().ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => { services.AddHostedService<MyTestService>(); }).RunConsoleAsync();
```

Then within the MyTestService I have a StartupService.cs that contains the following Code in its Startup method.

```
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher()
var fileWatcherDirectoryPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileWatcherDirectoryPath"];
watcher.Path = fileWatcherDirectoryPath;        
    
// Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
// the renaming of files or directories.
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
    | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
    | NotifyFilters.FileName
    | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    
watcher.Filter = "*.*";
    
// Add event handlers.
watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
watcher.Created += OnChanged;
watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
    
// Begin watching.
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) =>
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
    Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}");

private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e) =>
    // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
    Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.OldFullPath} renamed to {e.FullPath}");
```

I took the simple application from Microsoft's documentation found in the link below and was able to get it work in a standalone console application but have been unsuccessful in getting it to work with my hosted service. I removed the using statement of course but I think once the hosted service spins up the watcher never receives events not quite sure why because I thought it ran its own threads. Any help to point me in the right direction and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

So hopefully this helps someone else but it was a scoped variable issue. When I made the FileSystemWatcher into a private field within my service class it worked.